# About the Mean Value Theorem in a Volterra-Hammerstein equation

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, functions

In a paper, while studying the existence of solutions to the Volterra-Hammerstein
integral equation
$$
x(t)=\int_{0}^{t} K(t, s) g(s, x(s)) d s, \quad T \in[0,1).
$$
where $K \in L^{1}$ is an scalar kernel, $B$ is a Banach space with the norm $\|.\|$ and $g:[0, T] \times$ $B \rightarrow B$.

The author used the following:

$$\left\{\int_{0}^{t} K(t, s) g(s, x(s)) d s: x \in \mathcal{C}([0,1),B)\right\}\subset t. \overline{\operatorname{conv}}\left\{g(s, x(s)): x \in \mathcal{C}([0,1),B), s \in[0, t]\right\}.$$

**My question is about the kernel $K(t,s)$, why it is not involved in the second part of the inclusion?**

---

Let us recall the  Mean Value Theorem:

> Let the function $f: I \rightarrow B$ to be integrable on $I$, then
> $$\int_{J} f(s) d s \in |J| \overline{\operatorname{conv}}\big(f(J)\big),$$
>
> where $J \subseteq  I,\;|J|$ is the length of $J$ and
> $\overline{\operatorname{conv}}\big(f(J)\big)$ is the closed convex hull of $f(J)$.